# Determinant Properties for Relating $H^\top AH$ to $\det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $H \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a column vector.

I am trying to relate the scalar quantity $H^\top A H $ and $\det(A).$ Is there a determinant property to do the above?

Thanks

Comment: Consider $\det(H^TAH)$. Is it defined? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the values of $H^TAH$ can tell us some information about $\det(A)$, but knowing $\det(A)$ doesn't tell us much about what the value of $H^TAH$ might be in general.

If $\det(A)=0$, $A$ is singular, and that there is some vector $H$ such that $H^TAH=0$ (since it's singular, there must be some vector such that $AH=0$, more specifically).
This is about all we get.
For instance, if we have
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\quad H=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
then $H^TAH=x$ but $\det(A)=0$.

Even if $\det(A)\neq 0$, the situation isn't any better.
For the pair
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\ 0 & 1/x
\end{bmatrix},\quad H=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
we have $\det(A)=1$ but $H^TAH=x$ and can be made as large as we would like.
So there's no way to bound $H^TAH$ in terms of $\det(A)$ in general.

On the other hand, if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then knowing the value of $H^TAH$ for all $H$ does tell us information about the $\det(A)$, since both of these have connections to the eigenvalues of $A$.
For any matrix $A$, we have that
$$\det(A)
=\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i
,$$
the product of all of the $n$ eigenvalues of $A$.
And for symmetric matrices, the quantity
$$
\frac{H^TAH}{H^TH}
$$
(known as the Rayleigh quotient) for $H\neq 0$ is very closely connected to eigenvalues.
For instance, the minimum/maximum values of the Rayleigh quotient are the minimum/maximum eigenvalues of $A$.
This can be used to give a relationship between the two, although it isn't particularly sharp:
$$
|\det(A)|
=
\prod_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|
\leq
\left(
\max_{H\neq 0}
\left|
\frac{H^TAH}{H^TH}
\right|
\right)
^n.
$$
The Rayleigh quotient has some other properties that could be used in this way; for instance, its value at its stationary points are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$.

(Finally, in the event that $A$ is not symmetric, the Rayleigh quotient of $A$ will only tell us information about the eigenvalues of the matrix $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$, which isn't useful in this case.)